# Finding optimal diagonal weight matrix to minimize the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Let $\Sigma_0$, $\Sigma_1$ be known $p\times p$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrices, and $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$ be $p\times p$ prespecified matrices. Define $W=\text{diag}(w_1,\ldots,w_p)$ as the a diagonal matrix, where $w_i\in[0,1]$ for $i=1,\ldots,p$.

Find the optimal diagonal weight matrix $W^*$ such that for any $W$,

\begin{equation}
\left\{W\Gamma_0+(I-W)\Gamma_1\right\}^{-1}\left\{W\Sigma_0W+(I-W)\Sigma_1(I-W)\right\}\left\{W\Gamma_0+(I-W)\Gamma_1\right\}^{-1\top}
-\left\{W^*\Gamma_0+(I-W^*)\Gamma_1\right\}^{-1}\left\{W^*\Sigma_0W^*+(I-W^*)\Sigma_1(I-W^*)\right\}\left\{W^*\Gamma_0+(I-W^*)\Gamma_1\right\}^{-1\top}
\end{equation}
is non-negative definite.

My first thought is to transform this problem to be an optimization problem
\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize} & \left\{W\Gamma_0+(I-W)\Gamma_1\right\}^{-1}\left\{W\Sigma_0W+(I-W)\Sigma_1(I-W)\right\}\left\{W\Gamma_0+(I-W)\Gamma_1\right\}^{-1\top} \\
\text{subject to} & W \succeq 0 \\ & I - W \succeq 0. \end{array}

This is applied to finding the most efficient estimator in statistics. Really appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: Are $W$ and $W^\star$ distinct? Must $W^\star$ also be diagonal?

Comment: Yes. $W^*$ is also a diagonal matrix with the same boundary as $W$. Namely, $W^*=\text{diag}(w_1^*,\ldots,w_p^*)$, where $w_i^*\in[0,1]$ for $i=1,…,p$.

Comment: This may be trivial but choosing $W^\star = W$, the original matrix becomes $0$ and is positive semidefinte. This fullfills the requirement that the matrix should be non-negative definite.

Comment: Is there any more information on the relation between $\Sigma_i$ or $\Gamma_i$, their structure or their rank? For example, the rank of these matrices will be determined by the rank of the matrix in the middle (the extreme ones are invertible, so they are full rank). If rank($\Sigma_0$) > rank($\Sigma_1$), then you'd need to have $W^* = 0$, as the negative matrix should always have smaller or equal rank than the positive one, otherwise you are guaranteed to find a negative eigenvector of the difference.

Comment: $\Gamma_1$ and $\Sigma_1$ are of full rank.The relation between matrices are rank$(\Gamma_0)<$rank$(\Gamma_1)$ and rank$(\Sigma_0)<$rank$(\Sigma_1)$.